# syntax error with using test -a in unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to shell script. I tried to run the following but it gives me syntax error. What is wrong?

```
[[ $# -gt 0 -a $(file -b $1) != 'JPEG'* ]]
```

Comment: `-a` means "logical and" with the `test`, or `[` command, but with `[[` it means "object is accessible".  Use `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's see:

```
$ shellcheck myscript 

In myscript line 1:
[[ $# -gt 0 -a $(file -b $1) != 'JPEG'* ]]
            ^-- SC2108: In [[..]], use && instead of -a.
```

There you go. Here's a complete example (bring your own test files):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -gt 0 && $(file -b $1) != 'JPEG'* ]]
then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

in action:

```
$ chmod +x myscript
$ ./myscript
false
$ ./myscript test.jpg
false
$ ./myscript test.pdf
true
```